# Xen Time Sync Issue after Conversion to VMWare

Tags: xen

I have a Windows 7 system that was converted from Xen to VMWare ESXI 5.0. Problem is i think the Xen sync is still adjusting the time 3 hours into the future. Is there any way I can disable this feature, I did try google but no luck finding a good solution. I am thinking perhaps uninstalling the Xen drivers but not sure, any help would be great.

Comment: Are you sure you have your timezone set properly?  Have you install the vmware gust tools in Windows 7 VM?

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this is useful.

[Disable Time Synchronization](http://xtravirt.com/disabling-virtual-machine-guest-host-time-synchronization-multiple-hypervisors)

Steps provided in the link in case the link goes dead as mentioned by @tombull89

```
From the Virtual Machine Guest operating system, edit the VMware Tools properties.
1. Select the Options tab.
2. Uncheck Time synchronization between the virtual machine and the ESX Server operating system.
3. Click Apply.
```

While this will prevent the ongoing, periodic guest-to-host time synchronization, be aware that, by default, it will still occur once during each of the following each Virtual Machine operations:

```
Resume from suspend
Migrate with VMotion to another host
Take or revert to a snapshot
Shrink the virtual disk
Restart the VMware Tools service
Power on
```

To also disable time synchronization for the above operations, shut down the Virtual Machine, edit its configuration file (.vmx) and specify the following options:

```
tools.syncTime = "0"
time.synchronize.continue = "0"
time.synchronize.restore = "0"
time.synchronize.resume.disk = "0"
time.synchronize.shrink = "0"
time.synchronize.tools.startup = "0"
```

Comment: Could you summarize the contents of the link incase the link goes dead or down?